# NSButton with an Image

Tags: macos, cocoa, image, nsbutton

I have a question. I have a button on my .xib and a background image. I set an image to my button through the attributes inspector, but when I run the program and press the button, this happens:

[image]

If I don't press it, it looks fine. What's wrong?

Comment: What exactly did go wrong? Without the original images, it's hard to tell. Did you try changing the scaling?

Comment: I don't know - you tell us what's wrong and what you expect to be right

Comment: how can i get rid of the white around the button? the button's image is a png. that's the only thing wrong with the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `setHighlightsBy:` property on the cell. It's probably set to `NSChangeBackgroundCellMask` by default. Try setting `NSContentsCellMask` (if you have an alternate 'pressed' image) or `NSNoCellMask`.